# Purpose of Gaussian RBF kernel

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

Does anyone know the purpose of a Gaussian RBF kernel? Is it to classify data that is not linearly separable? What kind of representation bias does it capture?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search shows [an excellent Andrew Ng course on RBF kernels](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex8/ex8.html):

> linearly non-separable features often become linearly separable after they are mapped to a high dimensional feature space. However, we don't ever need to compute the feature mappings explicitly: we only need to work with their kernels, which are easier to compute. Therefore, it's possible to create a very complex decision boundary based on a high dimensional (even infinite dimensional) feature mapping but still have an efficient computation because of the kernel representation.

While a representation bias is just a complete searching of an incomplete hypothesis space, a *preference* bias is an incomplete searching of a complete hypothesis space, which an RBF kernel can classify data despite by separating the vector/feature space.